# Spring Data Jpa Oracle Could not Create Table

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

My application yaml conf is given below

```
 spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.184.33.67:1521:YYY
    username: XXX
    password: XXX
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      naming:
        ddl-auto: create
```

When i try to create table on H2 or Mysql DB, They are created. On the other hand, When i change it to oracle, application is running but hibernate does not create tables. I use, ojdbc6-11.2.0.3, Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and spring cloud Finchley.M9, Db version is 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your structure should be like :

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

and not

> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.ddl-auto = create

Comment: I lost 5 hours and i could not see it from consul thanks @Vitek Bansal